# abaqus scripting: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Set' objects

Tags: python, compiler-errors, syntax-error, abaqus

I get the error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Set' objects
```

and the error is caused by my code

```
name=inst1name+'-'+setName
```

I know the problem is: `inst1name` is a set object, however this error never come up before when I run the script.

Do you know why is this? and how can I solve it?

Comment: `str(inst1name)`? what do you expect to happen when trying to concat  a set and a str?

Comment: _"I know the problem is: inst1name is a set object."_ I think it's the other way around. if `inst1name` was a set and `setName` was a string, you'd get `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'str'`. You get `cannot concatenate 'str' and 'set' objects` when the _first_ argument is a string and the _second_ argument is a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly convert the `set` to its string representation like this:

```
name = inst1name + '-' + str(setName)
```

But a better way would be to use string composition like this:

```
name = '%s-%s' % (inst1name, setName)
```

Or even `string.format` like this:

```
name = '{}-{}'.format(inst1name, setName)
```

Comment: thank you! I also tried your method to solve a similar problem, and this is the code after change:                                str(setsTuple) #setsTuple is a set                                      muscleNodes=setsTuple[1]                                                        however the same error comes out, why is it?